# how to format date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I cannot format a date.
 `dateFormat.format()` accepts a `Date` as argument. So I created a new `Date()`

It says the below Date() method is deprecated, and I get the below exception while running.

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:598)


public class MyDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Date date = new Date("2012-02-16T00:00:00.000-0500");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        System.out.println(stringDate); // how do I test this conversion??

    }
}
```

My database has date of the format - 2012-02-16T00:00:00.000-0500
I need to convert it to string of the format : dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss

I'm using Java6

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why can't you use the `SimpleDateFormat` to `parse` the `Date` too. More importantly, why aren't you using the new Java 8 DateTime API??

Comment: If you want to add a solution, add your own answer. If you think your own answer is a better answer than any of the others, you can accept it too. Please don't edit answers into questions.

Comment: ok, Sure , will follow that. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read in the date "2012-02-16T00:00:00.000-0500" you should probably use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) it like so:

```
DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = parseFormat.parse("2012-02-16T00:00:00.000-0500");
```

Along with the rest of your code this writes:

```
16-Feb-2012 05:00:00
```

The parse format pattern letters are listed in the [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The `T` is escaped with apostrophes.

*This answer assumes Java 7, or you would be using the new [date & time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) from Java 8*

Comment: @spiderman. You don't need to update your question with the solution; that's why you mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Even after reading your solution, it took some time for me to put things correctly, so I always update the post to show the complete solution, which might help someone later

Comment: you're right, I 'll post as seperate answer just as a placeholder

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Andy Brown. In addition to what Andy Brown has answered, I'm posting the complete snippet

**Complete Solution:**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class SampleDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                 "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        Date date = parseFormat.parse("2012-03-16T00:00:00.000-0500");
        String strDate = parseFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);

        // if you get date of type 'java.sql.Date' directly from database cursor like
         //rs.getDate("created_date"), just pass it directly to format()

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(stringDate);

    }
}

/*
Output:

2012-03-16T01:00:00.000-0400
16-Mar-2012 01:00:00

*/
```

you can also convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` like this,

```
String dateString = "03-11-2012";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    java.util.Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());
// set the input param type as OracleTypes.DATE and pass the input param date as sqlDate
```